# Import multiple lua files at once?

Tags: lua

How do I import multiple lua files in another lua file and use them. I am using

`dofile("/some/paht/file.lua")`

for each and every file. What is the best way  to import multiple lua files at once? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/15.html

Comment: I read that article, But it dint get all modules defined  individual files at once.  I have 5 .lua files and each one define its own package  now i want to use 5 packages in 6th .lua file how can i do it?

Comment: What is the problem with having the 6th file require the other 5?

Comment: Yeah you are correct there is no problem in it .I followed same way. But for this i need to write separate dofile("file/to/path") for each file. Instead of this it,can i do it in simpler way like import package in java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [require](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require) to load modules. Using `dofile` works, but `require` will cache the loaded module, and you can control where to look for modules via [package.path](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path).

You can load multiple modules by just calling `require` for each one.

```
require 'file1'  --> load ./file1.lua
require 'file2'  --> load ./file2.lua
```

If you need to load a module from somewhere not in the default path you can update `package.path` before calling require:

```
package.path = '/some/path/?.lua;'..package.path
```

If your modules have a return value (ex. a table of functions), which is common for Lua modules, then set a variable to the return value of `require`.

```
local file1 = require 'file1'  --> load file1.lua
local file2 = require 'file2'
```

If you want to load multiple files in one go; create a function that takes a table of module names, requires each one, and then returns them all.

```
local function import(t)
    for i, v in ipairs(t) do
        t[i] = require(v)
    end
    return table.unpack(t)
end

local file1, file2 = import{'file1', 'file2'}
```

Comment: The final solution using the import is extremely well done.

Answer (score 1):

You can precompile all files into a single one with

```
luac -o bundle.luac file1.lua file2.lua file3.lua
```

and then do a single

```
dofile"bundle.luac"
```